# How do you define long and short run in an ARDL model?

Tags: time-series, ardl

I am writing up my regression analysis of an ARDL model which includes the long run equation and the short run dynamics. My reader however, would like to know what I mean by *long run* and *short run*. Can someone define these terms for me, please?

Comment: I know Dave Giles has a few nice posts on ARDL modelling in his blog ["Econometrics Beat: Dave Giles' Blog"](http://davegiles.blogspot.com). Probably you will find an answer there.

Comment: I am not seeing it being explained in Dave Giles blog

Comment: please check out this link and see if it answers your question: http://www.reed.edu/economics/parker/s14/312/tschapters/S13_Ch_3.pdf